# I Want to create a background service with get data from api in every second so how to create it?

Tags: android, service, android-service, background-service, android-background

I need to create a background service that can get data from API every second because I want to monitor some data and add that data to the database.

I try to create a service like below it's working fine and also works in the background when the app kill by the user but the problem is when I used my application longly the application UI totally hangs and stuck

- My Service Class Code

  ```
   public class MonitoringService extends Service {
   private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
   private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }


   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       startForeground();
       getLiveUpdate();
       AlramHendaler alramHendaler = new AlramHendaler(this);
       alramHendaler.setAlram();

       return START_STICKY;

   }


   private void getLiveUpdate() {

       //I use TimerTask for execute thread in background 

       ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
       MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask(() -> {

           //Here I get data every second from API
           Call<ArrayList<TempModel>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance(ResponceData.BASE_URL_1).getMyApi().getData(url);
           call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<TempModel>>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<TempModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<TempModel>> response) {
                  //get Response
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<TempModel>> call, Throwable t) {

               }
           });

       });
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }


   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   private void startForeground() {
       Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainProcedureActivity.class);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
       NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID, "InOT", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
       NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Utills.addErrorInDatabase(this, "Service Is Connected");
       assert manager != null;
       manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
       startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID)
               .setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
               .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText("Service is running background").setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build());
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
       Utills.addErrorInDatabase(this, "Service Is Disconnected");
       Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, CheckServiceBrodcast.class);
       sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
   }
  }
  ```

The problem with this service is that the application is used continuously then the application not responding and is terminated by Android OS

So, How to solve this issue, and how to create a proper background service to get data every second and add it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     //your code
     return START_NOT_STICKY;
 }
```

if you use return START_STICKY:
The System will try to restart the background service if it's kiled, this can cause issues sometimes, when you use START_NOT_STICKY, the System won't try to restart it. I think the reason why your app is freezing is because the system is trying to restart a dead service.

Comment: But I want to run this service in also background when the app is not in the foreground so I think `START_STICKY` flag is required

Comment: No it's not required, a foreground service runs in the background pretending to be a "Foreground Service", the flag  START_STICKY is only for restarting the service if it's destroyed by the system.

Comment: But what happens when my service is terminated so it automatically restarts or not?

Comment: if you use START_STICKY then it will attempt to restart it, if you say START_NOT_STICKY, then it won't. try this `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Okay I try `START_NOT_STICKY` but no luck issue is the same as not solving

Comment: are you getting an ANR? also if you want to update it every second use `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Yes I getting ANR, I used this because I want to monitor data and store this data in the database

Comment: add `Log.d(METHOD, "before");` and `Log.d(METHOD, "after");` before and after every method, (where METHOD is a String with the name of the method)this is the easiest way to find the cause of the ANR. You're probably trying to access something after it has become null.

Comment: Okay I Try This

Comment: Is any Other Solution you have?

Comment: You should move `super.onDestroy();` after your code in the onDestroy() method